# Why does Math instanceof Math throw an error?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following JavaScript

```
Math instanceof Math
```

throw the error

```
TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>
```

?

Comment: It sounds to me like `Math` is an object, not a constructor function.

Comment: Because `Math` is not a function. `typeof Math --> "object"`. More info: http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Math` is not a constructor, unlike `Object`.

See [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> object instanceof constructor
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `object`:
>      The object to test.
>
> `constructor`:
>      Function to test against